# Java parse exception

Tags: java, parsing, exception

I created a hibernate program and when i tried to format the date i am getting the below mentioned error:

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat formatter1=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date1=null;
Date date2=null;
Date startdate=(Date)formatter.parse(startDate);
Date enddate=(Date)formatter.parse(endDate);
```

How to resolve the parse exception?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us the content of **startDate** string variable.

Comment: How does startDate look like? Show it too.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to parse `startdate` but it doesn't actually contain any date and hence the `Exception`.

You should try:

```
String strDate = "2012-10-20";
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date startDate = formatter.parse(strDate);
```